# Python pip install reportlab error

Tags: python, windows, installation, reportlab

I am trying to install reportlab for python. I have Windows 7, Python 2.7 and Visual Studio 2013 and I am using the command line "pip install reportlab" but it is not working.

I have the pip log file data that was generated - what is the best way to get this file attached to my question so that others can view it?

Here is the last section of the log file/command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION=\"2.3.12\" -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcc:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb_rgba_affine.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb_rgba_affine.obj

art_rgb_rgba_affine.c

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION=\"2.3.12\" -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcc:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_intersect.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_intersect.obj

art_svp_intersect.c

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION=\"2.3.12\" -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcc:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_render_aa.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_render_aa.obj

art_svp_render_aa.c

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION=\"2.3.12\" -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl -Ic:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcc:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_misc.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_misc.obj

art_misc.c

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:init_renderPM build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\_renderPM.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1\gt1-parset1.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1\gt1-dict.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1\gt1-namecontext.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\gt1\gt1-region.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_vpath_bpath.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb_pixbuf_affine.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb_svp.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_vpath.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_vpath_stroke.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_ops.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_vpath.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_vpath_dash.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_affine.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rect.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb_affine.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb_affine_private.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_rgb_rgba_affine.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_intersect.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_svp_render_aa.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\libart_lgpl\art_misc.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\reportlab\graphics\_renderPM.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\_renderPM.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\_renderPM.pyd.manifest

   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\_renderPM.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\_renderPM.exp

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\mt.exe -nologo -manifest build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\_renderPM.pyd.manifest -outputresource:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\reportlab\graphics\_renderPM.pyd;2



build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab\src\rl_addons\renderPM\_renderPM.pyd.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.

error: command 'mt.exe' failed with exit status 31

----------------------------------------

Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\kvincent\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-kvincent\\reportlab\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-zbzt97-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 271, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1185, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 592, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\kvincent\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-kvincent\\reportlab\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-zbzt97-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\kvincent\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kvincent\reportlab
```

Comment: Just post what shows up in the command line, that would be sufficient.

Comment: The log file is 46,000 characters long.....I think my limit is 30,000

Comment: I was referring to the error you get in the command line, not the actual log file. If it's not installing you must be getting an error in there.

Comment: I have added the error part....I seem to be missing a vcvarsall.bat file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing the file, it's just unable to be found.

Try these codes in the following order:

`python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32`

then:

`python setup.py install`

Comment: I ran the codes in order as you suggested and then tried to install reportlab again...same error. My computer is 64 bit....is mingw32 the correct compiler?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed? If so, what version?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Try `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%` then the previous steps please.

Comment: This did make some difference....it looks like the vcvarsall.bat file has been found as there is no longer any mention of it.....but I still got an installation error......I have updated the log file/command line data in the original question above

Comment: Check to see if it got installed.`import reportlab` 
`print reportlab.Version`. The error that you obtained `error: command 'mt.exe' failed with exit status 31` is possibly related to Antivirus

Comment: It does not look like it got installed. I received an ImportError saying No module named reportlab

Comment: Can you disable your antivirus then try installing it? No need to set VS tool again.

Comment: I temporarily disabled my AV and tried to install it again....this got me further but I still got another installation error. I have updated the log file/command line data above

Comment: Let's try this now... Sorry it's taking so long. Go to `‪..\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py` and add `ld_args.append('/MANIFEST')` after `ld_args.append('/MANIFESTFILE:' + temp_manifest)`. Should be around like 670 (that's where mine is but I'm using Python3.4)

Comment: Actually it looks like it is now installed....after my last update above, I tried to install it again....then when I tried to import reportlab, I got no ImportError. I can also see the reportlab folders in Lib\Site-packages. If I run into any more issues I will look at the instructions in your last comment. But it looks like it has finally installed. Thank you so much for your great help.

Comment: Yes and no....I disabled the AV and tried to install it...got another installation error which I pasted above.....I believe I tried to import reportlab but got an ImportError....I reenabled the AV and tried the pip install again....this took me even further, gave me yet another installation error but when I tried to import reportlab, it gave me no error....and the folders were visible in Lib\site-packages

Comment: Glad it worked, reason I asked about the AV is because it may cause a connection failure, `exit status 31` but it shouldn't have prevented the installation. Either way, hope you get no more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Get a precompiled binary here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#reportlab

Installing non-compiled Python libraries on Windows is a pain: don't put yourself through it. Just make it simple: get something already made for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found issues to install reportlab in python 2.7

I recommend you to upgraded with python 3.6 and you can install reportlab using pip command

'pip install reportlab'